# the order of a quotient group element

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm looking at the solution to this question and there's one part that doesn't make sense to me.

Let $G$ be a group and $N$ a normal subgroup of $G$. 
Prove that the order of the element $gN$ in $G/N$ is $n$, where $n$ is the smallest positive integer such that $g^n$ is an element of $N$.

The first part of the solution says you take $(gN)^n$ = $g^nN$ = $1$. Why is that last equality true? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: $g^n\in N$, then $g^nN=N$ the unit element in $G/N$.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that $\;gN=hN\iff h^{-1}g\in H\;$ , and thus $\;(gN)^n:= g^nN=1\iff g^n\in N\;$ , taking into account that here $\;1= N=$ the unit element in the quotient $\;G/N\;$